# when I try to center vertically in bootstrap the div gets narrowed

Tags: css

I want to center the content in the divs. But if I use my-auto it centers it but narrows the div as I show in the images:
without my-auto: https://postimg.cc/CBJr0t3L
with my-auto: https://postimg.cc/svL81kvM
As you can see when using my-auto I focus the content on the div, but narrow it down.
How can I do so that it does not constrict it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="css/bootstrap.css" TYPE="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos_menu.css">
    </head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row " style="min-height:75px;">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-1 bg-primary " style="z-index:3;">
    <!--<div class="hamburguer">-->
        <div id="header">
                                <ul class="nav">
                                        <li><img class="icono"  src="hamburguer.png">
                                                <ul>
                                                        <li><a href="">Tienda</a>
                                                                <ul>
                                                                    <li><a href="">Ver todo</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="">Armarios</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="">Sillas</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="">Sillones</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="">Sofás</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="">Mesas</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="">Mesillas y cajoneras</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="">Lámparas</a></li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a href="blog_principal.php">Blog</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                        <li><a href="minimalista.php">Estilo minimalista</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="nordico.php">Estilo nórdico</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="retro.php">Estilo retro</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="rustico.php">Estilo rústico</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="clasico.php">Estilo clásico</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="exteriores.php">Espacios exteriores</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="fusion_estilos.php">Fusión de estilos</a></li>                     
                                                        </li>
                                                </ul>
                                        </li>
                                                </ul>
                                        </li>   
                                </ul>

                        </div>              

    </div> <!-- div col-->

<div class="col-sm-10 col-lg-6 bg-danger ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
        <a href="#">BOKDEKÓ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">    
        <a href ="#">Cuenta</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
        <a href ="#">Registrarse</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">    
        Busca productos
        <input type=text name=buscar size='12' maxlength='15' value=''>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div><!--div col-->
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-5 bg-info "><!--align-self-center-->
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-3 ">
                <a href="#">Mi lista</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 bg-success">
                <a href ="#">Carrito</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 bg-warning">
                <a href="#">Hola</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!--div col-->
    </div> <!--div row-->
</div>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/utilidades.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

my-auto will automatically set the margins to only contain the content within them.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

If you want the margins to be greater then you'll have to override this styling in CSS. Have you tried adding a custom id to the div or you might have to use !important on the style you want to change.

https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Hope this helps, best of luck.